# Can't advance in different Jframe Form (Logger.getLogger method)

Tags: java, derby

I added [rs2xml](https://hacksmile.com/rs2xml-jar-free-download/) and [derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) in my libraries, it was working at the start but after adding the connection for derby and refresh function for my Tables, the `JFrame` form can't proceed to the next `JFrame` Form

These are the codes to move to the next `JFrame` but it's not working but there is no errors

```
int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                              "Are you sure you want to Continue to Stock Table?",
                                              "Confirm Button Message Box",
                                              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    try {
        new InformationofCafe().setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Menu.this, "Cancelled");
}
```

and these are the codes in the `JFrame` form that I wish to get to but it won't advance to that `JFrame` form.

```java
public class InformationofCafe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    int cursorRow = 0;

    public InformationofCafe() throws SQLException {
        initComponents();
        DoConnect();
        update_table();
    }

    void update_table() throws SQLException {
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STOCK");
        jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }

    public Connection DoConnect() {
        try {
            String host ="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//Downtown";
            String uName ="miguel";
            String uPass ="miguel";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                       ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM STOCK";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            int id_col = rs.getInt("ITEM");
            String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
            String description = rs.getString("DESCRIPTION");
            String amount = rs.getString("AMOUNT");

            TextItem.setText(id);
            TextDescription.setText(description);
            TextAmount.setText(amount);

            update_table();
        }
        catch (SQLException err) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(InformationofCafe.this,
                                          err.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new InformationofCafe().setVisible(true);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InformationofCafe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried everything I knew. Even searched the Internet on what to do but can't seem to find the solution. I know it's the `try` and `catch` in `logger.getlogger` that's causing the error I just don't know how to fix it :(

here is the error log

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at activity3.InformationofCafe.update_table(InformationofCafe.java:33)
at activity3.InformationofCafe.<init>(InformationofCafe.java:29)
at activity3.Menu.InformationActionPerformed(Menu.java:130)
at activity3.Menu.access$000(Menu.java:23)
at activity3.Menu$1.actionPerformed(Menu.java:62)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the `Logger` and replace it with `ex.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: will try and catch stay?

Comment: Yes. Inside the catch block, simply write `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: yes rs2xml, my bad

Comment: is there supposed to be an import to use that code?

Comment: No import required.

Comment: it's saying "Connection authentication failure occured. Reason: userid or password invalid"

Comment: Are you sure you created a user for the Derby database?

Comment: I also added the error logs

Comment: I should establish the Doconnect function i did in all of the jframe forms that i did?

Comment: Line 33 in file `InformationofCafe.java` is throwing `NullPointerException`. What is written on line 33?

Comment: rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STOCK");

Comment: it seems like for some reason the database i created is also not connecting

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with *Swing*. And I also don't understand why you tagged it with **sql-server** since you state that you are using [Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/).

You are failing to connect to the database, i.e. the following line of your code is throwing an exception.

```java
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
```

Subsequently, the `stmt` member of class `InformationofCafe` is not initialized and therefore is null.

The way your code handles the database connection error is to display the error message in a `JOptionPane`. That means your program continues to run and when it gets to the following line of your code, it throws `NullPointerException` because `stmt` is null.

```java
rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STOCK");
```

I suggest you write a simple program, without a GUI that tries to connect to Derby and then executes a SQL query. Once you get that right, you can fix the code in your GUI. Have you read the documentation for Derby?

You need to think about what you want your GUI program to do if there is a problem with connecting to the database or retrieving data from the database. You shouldn't just ignore it. And just displaying the error message is essentially ignoring the error.